# 04 Chevy Malibu classic new fuel filter cranks but does not turn over an it's not the theft system

Tags: starting, chevrolet, malibu

4 door . Classic model.gold in color.03 engine.has a new fuel filter.but won't start it cranks over.the theft system light isn't on.unplugged negative side of battery for 30 minutes then had it on the start position for 10 minutes an still won't start only crank's over an now there is a beeping sound

Comment: Am I reading this right, it has a 2003 engine in it (so the original was replaced) and now it's not starting? Does it show *any signs of life* when you are trying to start it? Or it just turns over and over with no other signs of life? Have you checked the car to see if there are any codes in the computer? (Yes, even after you unplugged the computer.) The reason I say this is because it can sometimes give you clues as to what's going on, even after you've wiped the memory. Helped me once when I forgot to plug in the crank position sensor during a clutch install ... argh!